# How do you read the HTML content of an Atom feed with Scala and Play framework 2.0?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am having difficulty extracting the html content from an Atom feed. In a controller, I can get the atom feed with:

```
val feed = ws.WS.url("http://foo.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?max-results=4").get()
val blog = feed.await(5000).get.xml
Ok(views.html.news(blog))
```

In the referenced news view, I have this block:

```
<div id="news">
     <ul class="thumbnails">
     @for( entry <- blog \ "entry") {
         @{var message = (entry \ "content").head match {case <content>{a}</content> => a.text }}
         <li class="span6 review"><div class="thumbnail">
             <article>
                <header><h2>@{(entry \ "title").text}</h2>
                    Published @{(entry \ "published").text}</header>
                 @Html({(entry \ "content" ).head match{case <content>{a}</content> => a.text} } )
                   </article></div></li>
     }
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Reading the XML content for 'title' and 'published is working fine.  But I am failing to cleanly display the html from the `<content type="html">...</content>` which contains an escaped string holding the blog post content.  I am getting some unexpected characters showing up (an Â in what should be white space), so the .

Has anyone found a better way to extract HTML content from an atom feed using Play Framework 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of how to do this came from Play 2.0 Ticket "No default UTF-8 charset for JSON WS response body"  at https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/474-no-default-utf-8-charset-for-json-ws-response-body

The default characterset for text in HTTP 1.1 is ISO-8859-1, but the atom feed specified UTF-8.  So apparently, the HMTL in the <content> tag was encoded in ISO-8859-1.  So, the goal is to read the XML Elem, convent the contents to a string, and then convert from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, since that is what my document uses.  Here is my code:

```
@Html({
    (entry \ "content" ).head
        match{case <content>{a}</content> => 
            new String(a.text.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") , "UTF-8")
        }
 })
```

If anyone sees a flaw in this, please feel free to show me the errors of my ways.