# Play Framework Ning WS API encoding issue with HTML pages

Tags: scala, http, character-encoding, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play Framework 2.3 and the WS API to download and parse HTML pages. For none-English pages (e.g Russian, Hebrew), I often get wrong encoding.

Here's an example:

```
def test = Action.async { request =>

    WS.url("http://news.walla.co.il/item/2793388").get.map { response =>
        Ok(response.body)
    }
}
```

This returns the web page's HTML. English characters are received ok. The Hebrew letters appear as Gibberish. (Not just when rendering, at the internal String level). Like so:

```
<title>29 ××¨×××× ×××¤×××ª ××©×××× ×× ×¤××, ××× ×©×××©× ××©×¨×××× - ×××××! ×××©××ª</title>
```

Other articles from the same web-site can appear ok.

using `cURL` with the same web-page returns perfectly fine which makes me believe the problem is within the WS API.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I found a solution [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701727/how-do-you-read-the-html-content-of-an-atom-feed-with-scala-and-play-framework-2/13319026#13319026).

Parsing the response as `ISO-8859-1` and then converting it to `UTF-8` like-so:

```
Ok(new String(response.body.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") , response.header(CONTENT_ENCODING).getOrElse("UTF-8")))
```

display correctly. So I have a working solution, but why isn't this done internally?

Comment: I believe this is done but the default is `utf-8`.

Comment: You can post an answer to your question and accept it by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here the solution I ended up using in production:

```
def responseBody = response.header(CONTENT_TYPE).filter(_.toLowerCase.contains("charset")).fold(new String(response.body.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") , "UTF-8"))(_ => response.body)
```

**Explanation:**

If the request returns a "Content-Type" header that also specifies a charset, simply return the response body sine the WS API will use it to decode correctly, otherwise, assume the response is ISO-8859-1 encoded and convert it to UTF-8